# What are the differences between G+ and G- bacteria?

Tags: evolution, microbiology, bacteriology, quorum-sensing

The distinction between Gram-positive and Gram-negative bacteria is based upon the [**Gram staining**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_staining) method, that reflects the bacterial wall physical properties.
However, this classification involves also a large number of differences between them. For example, the endospore formation usually occurs in Gram-positive bacteria and also the *quorum sensing* mechanism is different.

So what are those differences? Which of them are due to the cell wall thickness and membrane(s) composition and which instead to evolutionary divergences?

Comment: here's a partial answer... http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7118/what-are-gram-negative-and-positive-bacteria

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know there were distinct differences between gram-positive and gram-negative bacteria when it came to quorum sensing, but it seems as though there are:

> In gram negative bacteria, acyl-homoserine lactone type molecules serve as the main signalling molecules while lipid, peptide, and amino acid based signalling molecules infrequently serve as signalling molecules. Furthermore, in gram-negative bacteria, there is one well conserved mechanism for controlling quorum response. Gram-positive bacteria, on the other hand, use peptides or modified peptides as the primary means of signaling; and also differing from gram-negative bacteria, there are several different mechanisms found within the class which are used to gain quorum responses.

[Source](https://www.bio.cmu.edu/courses/03441/TermPapers/99TermPapers/Quorum/mechanisms.htm).

In G<sup>+</sup> bacteria, the two main quorum sensing mechanisms are apparently as follows:

1. Two-component signal transduction, in which the peptide signal works by binding to a sensor protein, histidine kinase, located in the cell membrane of the bacterium. The activation of the histidine kinase leads to phosphorylation of response-regulating protein, and interaction with another regulatory protein facilitates transcriptional activation.
2. Internalization, in which the signal molecules are transported into the responder cell to interact with intracellular effectors.

G<sup>-</sup> bacteria on the other hand, synthesize autoinducers, effector molecules that can diffuse freely through the cell membrane and trigger cell response when a certain concentration threshold is reached. I do not know how or if these differences are related to cell wall structure.

When it comes to endospore formation, all I know of the difference between the two is that this is by far most common in gram-positive bacteria.